# Creating dump of partition in windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, dump

I need create dump of EFI (windows loader) partition. (300 Mb)

Did you know simple tool to make it?

Also restoring partition feature from dump (in Linux or/and Windows) require.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the most general `dd` in GNU coreutils. Or maybe `partclone.fat` (and `partclone.restore`) in partclone will gives you a smaller image.

I am not sure if it's really useful to make a dump of the EFI System Partition though. You can recreate it with `diskpart` and `bcdboot` (by booting into the command prompt of a Windows installation cd/usb or so). The dump may not be useful for you since the BCD Store records inside may not apply anymore.